# Problema al renderizar objecto anidado en React y Firebase

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, reactjs

Tengo un problema al renderizar un objecto anidado en React, cuando hago la consulta de esta manera:

```js
componentDidMount(){
        refOkr.on('value', (snapshot) =>{
            const items = snapshot.val();
            const newState = [];
            for(const item in items){
                newState.push({
                    id: item,
                    nombre: items[item].nombre,
                    descripcion: items[item].descripcion,
                    equipo: items[item].equipo,
                    prioridad: items[item].prioridad,
                    tipo: items[item].tipo,
                    progreso: items[item].progreso,
                    rc: items[item].rc
                });
            }
            this.setState({
                items: newState
            });
```

me guarda los datos del objeto en el estado, pero "rc" es un objeto anidado y no se como renderizarlo, al imprimir el estado en la consola me lo muestra asi:

2:
descripcion: "MARS"
equipo: "JPL"
id: "-LkUHwhEVVy_xORCHHU3"
nombre: "NASA"
prioridad: "critica"
progreso: "100%"
 rc:
  -LpY2EQpGnrbzxaW3Wzi:
   actual: "34"
   esperado: "56"
   inicial: "12"
   inicio: "2019-01-01"
   nombre: "anidamiento"
   target: "123"
   termino: "2019-12-31"

toda la información que esta en "RC" no se como llamarla para renderizarla

asi es como  hago la renderizacion de los objetos que no estan anidados

```js
<section>
                    <h2>Consulta OKR</h2>
                    <div className="Wrapper">
                        {this.state.items && this.state.items.map((item, key) => {
                            return(
                                <div>
                                    <div>
                                    <label>{item.nombre}</label>
                                    <label>{item.equipo}</label>
                                    <label>{item.prioridad}</label>
                                    <label>{item.progreso}</label>
                                    
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            );
                        })}
                    </div>
                </section>
```

pero no se como renderizar la parte anidada que esta en rc, espero puedan ayudarme, gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0):

No tuve como probar el código directamente bajo el escenario que tienes pero en teoría deberías hacer algo así

```
<section>
    <h2>Consulta OKR</h2>
    <div className="Wrapper">
        {this.state.items && this.state.items.map((item, key) => {
            return(
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <label>{item.nombre}</label>
                        <label>{item.equipo}</label>
                        <label>{item.prioridad}</label>
                        <label>{item.progreso}</label>
                        { items[item].rc && Object.keys(items[item].rc).map(i => <label>items[item].rc[i]</label>) }
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        })}
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda man, no lo hice exactamente así pero igual me diste una idea.
Al final lo termine haciendo asi: 

Object.keys(rcs).map( key =>
         <p>{rcs[key].nombre}</p>
    )